# Eliminate or de-generalize "Equipment" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [equipment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment) tag was applied a lot back in October 2014, to many (but not all) questions concerning "equipment" for pets, from leashes and blood meters to water filters and pumps to bird seed storage.

This tag seems much too general to be of any use to anyone.

I recommend altering questions to use equivalent tags ([filters](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filters), [toys](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toys), [furniture](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/furniture)), making at most one additional, less-generic tag.  I've already altered several questions.

Remaining 3 questions include:

- 1 about dog grooming equipment also tagged [grooming](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grooming)
- 1 about pet medical equipment also tagged [medical](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical)
- 1 about dog leashes also tagged [leash-training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leash-training)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eliminated the tag as too general.

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about this one, and I think I added the equipment tag to a bunch of questions under my theory of "all Pets.SE questions should have at least 2 tags" (which was discussed in chat at some point).

Each question should have a tag relating to the species of animal in the question (dog, cat, rabbit, fish, etc), and a second tag relating to the subject of the question.

For example, [leash-training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leash-training) is a popular tag, but leash training dogs is very different in method and popularity from leash training cats or other animals. It's useful to be able to search for both [leash-training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leash-training) and [cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cats) if I'm training my cat.

I suspect I had a handful of questions with one tag and what they had in common was that they weren't really about a specific type of pet, but about the equipment that was used with them (and that tag already existed).

I'm leaning towards believing that the questions should be tagged with the species that they are applicable to, (even if, with the diabetes blood sugar meter, that's pretty much everything) but I'll open a new question about that.

Comment: In the diabetes case, "medical equipment" might have worked, but it's the only one. And how does a glucose meter relate to a leash or the equipment given to a charity, or the additional equipment needed for a reef tank beyond a filter and a heater? I agree that leash training in animal-specific cases should be tagged "dogs" or "cats" or whatever, but in this case equipment was only used for very few tags before the retagging began, and even those originals were questionably tagged IMHO.

Comment: I found several questions regarding leashes that either didn't have leash-training tag or had nothing to do with training a pet on a leash.  These, yes a "leash" tag would make sense.

Comment: I would add that [tag:aquarium-equipment] might be a useful generalization, but I'm not an aquarium owner and can't attest to that.